# i am trying "AES/CCM/PKCS5Padding" encryption in java but i am getting some exception can any one help me how to do encryption using CCM code

Tags: java, encryption, aes, jce

```
public class AESCCMEncryption {
     public static int AES_KEY_SIZE = 128 ;
     public static int TAG_BIT_LENGTH = 128 ;
     public static String ALGO_TRANSFORMATION_STRING = "AES/CCM/PKCS5Padding" ;
     public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {


    SecretKey aesKey = null ;
    String message="messageToEncrypt";
    try {
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES") ;  
        keygen.init(AES_KEY_SIZE) ; 
        aesKey = keygen.generateKey() ;
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgoExc) { System.out.println("Key being request is for AES algorithm, but this cryptographic algorithm is not available in the environment "  + noSuchAlgoExc) ; System.exit(1) ; }
    byte[] encryptedText = aesEncrypt(message, aesKey) ;
    byte[] decryptedText = aesDecrypt(encryptedText, aesKey) ; 

    System.out.println("Decrypted text " + new String(decryptedText)) ;

}
     public static byte[] aesEncrypt(String message, SecretKey aesKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
         Cipher c = null ;
                c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_TRANSFORMATION_STRING); 
                c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey) ;
                byte[] cipherTextInByteArr = null ;
               cipherTextInByteArr = c.doFinal(message.getBytes()) ;
              return cipherTextInByteArr ;
 } 
     public static byte[] aesDecrypt(byte[] encryptedMessage, SecretKey aesKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
         Cipher c = null ;
              c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_TRANSFORMATION_STRING); // Transformation specifies algortihm, mode of operation and padding
              c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey) ;
              byte[] plainTextInByteArr = null ;
              plainTextInByteArr = c.doFinal(encryptedMessage) ;
          return plainTextInByteArr ;
       }
}
```

i am getting unsupported exception i am using java 1.8 version
if i am wrong can help me how to achieve the "AES/CCM/PKCS5Padding"
is necessary to add IV vector specification for encryption

Comment: You need to find a Security Provider that supports CCM mode. The default Sun JCE doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late, sorry for that - I have been researching how to do AES/CCM myself.

At any rate, the bouncycastle API supports CCM. It is pretty simple to add if you don't already have it as it is just a .jar file. You can head over to the java download page [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) to get the .jar.

However, you can see your current security providers by running the below code:

```
        Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
        for (int i = 0; i < providers.length; i++){
            Log.e("Provider", "Name: " + providers[i].getName() + " Version: " + providers[i].getVersion());
        }
```

I get the below output:

[image]

After a quick search, and it's already pretty obvious, but "BC Version: 1.52" is Bouncy Castle.

I also found an example .pdf that says "PKCS7Padding is often also referred to as PKCS5Padding." I'm not using padding, so i'll have to let you do the research on that. You can find that article [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf). The quote is on page 17, but you can probably find it faster with a CTRL-F, then paste in PKCS5Padding. The examples are only of CBC and EBC though.

As a side note, you can see on [this](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) page that PKCS is supported.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes JCE uses the name PKCS5Padding for what is really PKCS7 (in most cases), but CCM doesn't use any padding at all. Using BC is indeed an answer, probably the best one, although it is possible to construct CCM out of CTR+CBCMAC with some work.

Answer (score 0):

Due to global security concerns, the default JRE does not include support for more advanced encryption. You must download the "Unlimited Security" patch - current link is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Download the patch and follow the instructions in the `README.TXT` file contained therein.

Only clients located in "sanctioned" countries are allowed to download the patch.

There is of course no chance that uses will use a VPN to dodge that restriction, or that the patch is available via file sharing software.

Comment: Oracle-formerly-Sun Java's unlimited policy only affects key sizes/strengths over 128 bits, and is irrelevant to this problem, although it is a good answer for some _other_ problems.